# Service connection with name X already exists. Only a user having Administrator/User role permissions on service connection X can see it

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, devops, azure-aks

I got the following error when I try to deploy application using Azure DevOps technique ,

After I connect Azure with Github and connect it with my application I opened the YML file.

Then, I add the task "Azure app service deploy",

But I got the following error when I selected Azure subscription and clicked the authorize button

"Service connection with name Windows Azure MSDN - Visual Studio Premium(xxxxxxxxxxxxx) already exists. Only a user having Administrator/User role permissions on service connection Windows Azure MSDN - Visual Studio Premium(xxxxxxxxxxxxx)  can see it."

Please check the attached photo for more clarification.

[image]

Comment: Could you include what role you have on that service connection? Refer this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65207368/getting-permissions-error-when-trying-to-deploy-to-a-azure-resource-in-a-pipelin).

Comment: I can reproduce the issue when my account is a Creator of the service connection. Trying the suggestion assigning my account with User/Administrator role, which is shared by Sridevi, works for me. @Eng Sabreen Saber, would you please try it in your org and let us know if it works for you?

Answer (score 1):

The users who have **`Administrator`** or **`User`** role on a service connection can use this service connection. The **`Reader`** role can see the service connection but not use it. One way is to replace that service connection with new one with a different name.

**Project settings**->**Service connections**->**New Service Connection**->**Azure Resource Manager**->**Service principal (automatic)**->**Next**, select your corresponding Subscription and then type your new service connection in the Service Connection name box.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/PXTvJfx.png]

Now, you will own a new service connection with new name that connected to your VS premium subscription.

Another workaround is

- Got to the Project settings page of the Azure DevOps project you already setup.
- On the left pane, under "Pipelines", click on "Service connection"
- Your connection name should appear. Click on it.
- In the upper right section, click on the 3 vertical dots and choose "Security".

[image: https://i.imgur.com/dqYLoBp.png]

- Under project permission, choose the project you want this connection to be available and edit the permissions accordingly.

[image]

You can refer official [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to manage service connection.